# Multiple filter using lambda in python on rethinkdb?

Tags: python, lambda, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am trying to filter the array object inside a table. Here is a case where I have filtered and it works perfectly.

```
tags = ["school", "hollywood"]
tagsLambda =  lambda post: (post["tags"].contains(tags[0])) | (post["tags"].contains(tags[1]))
d = r.db("test").table("posts").filter(
    tagsLambda
).run()
```

But, My question is I am doing the lambda operation manually, instead I want `tagsLambda` to filter all the `tags`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
tags = ["school", "hollywood"]
r.db("test").table("posts").filter(
  lambda post: post["tags"].contains(lambda tag:
    r.expr(tags).contains(tag)
  )
).run(conn)
```

See http://rethinkdb.com/api/python/contains/

Answer (score 1):

```
tags = ["school", "hollywood"]
tagsLambda =  lambda post: ( 
eval('|'.join(
           [r'(post["tags"].contains("' + tag + '"))' for tag in tags]
    ))
)
d = r.db("test").table("posts").filter(tagsLambda).run()
```

`[ r'post["tags"].contains("' + tag + '")' for tag in tags ]` is a list comprehension. It builds a list of strings like `(post["tags"].contains("school"))` for each tag in tags. The `'|'.join` operation builds a string from the list of strings with '|' in between like `(post["tags"].contains("school")) | (post["tags"].contains("hollywood"))`. eval evaluates the whole string.

The above code can be simplified using `reduce` as

```
tags = ["school", "hollywood"]
tagsLambda =  lambda post:
    reduce(lambda x,y: x | y, [ post["tags"].contains(tag) for tag in tags])

d = r.db("test").table("posts").filter(tagsLambda).run()
```

For Python 3, 'functools' has to be imported to use `reduce` and replace `reduce` with `functools.reduce`.

The second lambda can be replaced with a function.

```
import operator as op
reduce(op.or_, [ post["tags"].contains(tag) for tag in tags])
```

User generators for better result.

```
reduce(op.or_, ( post["tags"].contains(tag) for tag in tags))
```

Comment: Dude, this won't work. It should be an `or` operator that is for sure.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation on what this code actually does? Thanks

Comment: @iraycd why you need '|'? how can you filter by a single tag? I think '|' is only needed if you want to filter by multiple tags

Comment: @NizamMohamed That is what I really wanted. Your solution is great. I guess your solution will even work with `&` operations. :)